# Check if an array contains elements of another array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, compare, equality

I need to check if an array contains at least one or more elements of another array and print them out in swift.
This is my situation:

```
var array1 = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"]
var array2 = ["user3, "user5", "user7", "user9, "user4"]

//I need to get back an array that says that both the arrays contains ex. "user3" and "user4"
```

I searched the web but i only found the opposite answer that helps t check if there is a difference between 2 arrays using `array.symmetricDifference()`

Any helps???  Thanks

Comment: what about basic looping and checking with .contains ?

Comment: Don't use arrays. Create two sets and get its intersection.

Comment: @LeoDabus can you explain more

Comment: `Set(array1).intersection(Set(array2))`

Comment: @LeoDabus ok and this produces another set containing the matches that can be converted again to an array?

Comment: `Array(result)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply create a set from your first collection and get its intersection with the other collection:

```
let array1 = ["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"]
let array2 = ["user3", "user5", "user7", "user9", "user4"]
let intersection = Array(Set(array1).intersection(array2)) // ["user4", "user3"]
```

---

Note that the order of the resulting collection is unpredictable. If you would like to preserve the order of the first collection you can create a set of the second collection and filter the elements that cannot be inserted to it:

```
var set = Set(array2)
let intersection = array1.filter { !set.insert($0).inserted }  // ["user3", "user4"]
```

---

You can also create your own intersection method on RangeReplaceableCollection:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func intersection<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) -> Self where S.Element == Element, Element: Hashable {
        var set = Set(sequence)
        return filter { !set.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let intersection = array1.intersection(array2)  // ["user3", "user4"]
```